# combinar arrays javascript

Tags: javascript

Buen dia. Tengo un problema con una array: Necesito combinar N numero de arrays por ejemplo:

```
var array = [
[0, 1, 2],
[3,4,5],
[6,7,8]
]
```

el resultado deberia ser:

```
var newArray = [
[0,3,6],
[1,4,7],
[2,5,8]
]
```

el array entrante tiene N arrays(dinamicos y con lontidudes dinamicas).

---

```
for (let x = 0, c = data.length; x < c; x++) {

var newArray = new Array();

for (let i = 0, count = data[x].length; i < count; i++) {     
    newArray.push(data[x][i]);
}

final = final.concat(newArray);
}
```

he probado con esto pero no funciona... Alguna ayuda por favor. Gracias por su tiempo. Slds y feliz tarde

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo conseguí de esta forma (funciona con longitudes dinámicas):

```js
var data = [
    [0,1,2,9],
    [3,4,5],
    [6,7,8]
 ]
    
var final = []
    
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    
    for (let j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {     
       
        if(!final[j]) final[j] = [];
       
        final[j].push(data[i][j])
       
    }
    
}
    
console.log(final);
```

Solo tienes que ponerlo en una función. ;)

Answer (score 3):

La idea sería algo así:

```
var array = [
[0, 1, 2],
[3,4,5],
[6,7,8]
]

var result;
for(j=0; j<array[j].length; j++){
    for(i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        alert(array[i][j]);
    }
}
```

En vez de un alert, metelo en una nueva variable y debería estar

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Podrias utilizar simplemente el metodo map:

```
 NewArray = array[0].map((col,i)=> array.map(fila => fila[i]))
```